# how to make list view of show type given below?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

[image]
Hi

can you please tell me how to make this type of listview in jquery mobile .I tried but I think my css not work .here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/aYF4H/

```
var Seriennr = new Array();
Seriennr[0] = "38894458885";
Seriennr[1] = "38894458885";
Seriennr[2] = "38894458885";
Seriennr[3] = "38894458885";
Seriennr[4] = "38894458885";

var artkilcode = new Array();
artkilcode[0] = "7058";
artkilcode[1] = "7058";
artkilcode[2] = "7058";
artkilcode[3] = "7058";
artkilcode[4] = "7058";


var beschreibung = new Array();
beschreibung[0] = "Hewlett Packard";
beschreibung[1] = "Hewlett Packard";
beschreibung[2] = "Hewlett Packard";
beschreibung[3] = "Hewlett Packard";
beschreibung[4] = "Hewlett Packard";

var aktuelleArt = new Array();
aktuelleArt[0] = "often";
aktuelleArt[1] = "often";
aktuelleArt[2] = "often";
aktuelleArt[3] = "often";
aktuelleArt[4] = "often";

var wareneingang = new Array();
wareneingang[0] = "1706";
wareneingang[1] = "1706";
wareneingang[2] = "1706";
wareneingang[3] = "1706";
wareneingang[4] = "1706";


$(document).ready(function () {
    for(var i=0;i<Seriennr.length;i++){
        $('#serialNumber').append('<li class="serialNumberRowclick" id="'+i+'"><div style="float:left; Display:inline;width:20%">'+Seriennr[i]+'</div><div  style="float:left; Display:inline;width:20%>'+artkilcode[i]+'</div><div  style="float:left; Display:inline;width:20%>'+beschreibung[i]+'</div><div  style="float:left; Display:inline;width:20%>'+aktuelleArt[i]+'</div><div  style="float:left; Display:inline;width:20%>'+wareneingang[i]+'</div></li>');
    }

    // Refreshing the list
    $('#serialNumber').listview('refresh');
});
```

Comment: You need to select `jquery-mobile.js` in the fiddle to make it work : http://jsfiddle.net/aYF4H/1/

Comment: Still it not look like same as in figure

Comment: Use table widget http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/

Comment: can you modified my fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your data to a table with CSS styling that matches your picture.  Something like this:

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Bd7Mp/1/)**

```
<table id="thetable" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th >Seriennr</th>
          <th >Artkilcode</th>
          <th >Beschreibung</th>
          <th >Aktuelle Art</th>
          <th >Wareneingang</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript to append the rows from your arrays:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    var allrows = '';
    for(var i=0;i<Seriennr.length;i++){
        allrows += '<tr>';
        allrows += '<td>'+Seriennr[i]+'</td>';
        allrows += '<td>'+artkilcode[i]+'</td>';
        allrows += '<td>'+beschreibung[i]+'</td>';  
        allrows += '<td>'+aktuelleArt[i]+'</td>';                
        allrows += '<td>'+wareneingang[i]+'</td>';
        allrows += '</tr>';
    }    
    $("#thetable tbody").empty().append(allrows);
});
```

CSS styling to achieve your look:

```
#thetable {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#thetable td, #thetable th {
    padding: 0.4em;
    text-shadow: none;
}
#thetable thead{
    background: #646464;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#thetable thead th:first-child{
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
#thetable thead th:last-child{
    -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
#thetable tbody tr{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: #fff;  
    color: #333;
}
#thetable tbody tr:nth-child(even) td:first-child{
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
#thetable tbody tr:nth-child(even) td:last-child{
    -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
#thetable tbody tr:nth-child(even){
    background: #d1d1d1;   
}
```